# QString to qint16

Tags: qt

I am trying to convert a `QString` to a `qint16` with

```
udpListenPort = ui->lineEdit_UdpListenPort->text().toShort();
```

but it converts `"40690"` to `0`.

I tried different casts and conversions but neither works. I think I can't see the wood for the trees here.

Answer (score 1):

You came most of the way, just change the **toShort()** to **toUShort()** to fix that.

```
udpListenPort = ui->lineEdit_UdpListenPort->text().toUShort();
```

`quint16` is just a typedef for unsigned short.

Comment: Using this 40690 is converted to -24844, as the qint16 flows over, as @Fryz pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

The maximal value a `qint16` (which is a `typedef short qint16; /* 16 bit signed */`) can hold is 32767 using two's complement, hence "40690" overflows and signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour.

Use `quint16` instead (which is a `typedef unsigned short quint16; /* 16 bit unsigned */`) and `ushort QString::toUShort(bool *ok = nullptr, int base = 10) const`.